# iOS display same UIBarButton throughout Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

currently I want to create some buttons and use it throughout all navigation controller. Let's say a "Search/Spotlight" button for searching, or a "add item button". these should be used throughout all of the navigation controller.

I tried to search through the internet but still don't get how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Or try use a UINavigationController category, and customize the back item, so no matter how many times it's pushed, just set the same view for navigationController's back item. Something like:

```
@implementation UIViewController (CustomNavigation)

- (void)setLeftBarButtonItem:(UIButton*)leftview
{    
    UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftview] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customItem; 
    [(UIButton*)self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `BaseViewController` as subclass of `UIViewController` and inherit all my ViewController with `BaseViewController` class.
In `viewDidLoad` put code to add your button to navigationBar.
All ViewControllers inherited with `BaseViewController` will have your button.

Just any UIViewController with navigationController and NavigationBar has own navigation buttons and you have to override it every time. With inherit you do it once.

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation BaseViewController 
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];
  }
  @end
```